# Jsreport rendering russian language

Tags: pdf-generation, jsreport, cyrillic

When I render jsreport pdf using phantom and html-to-pdf with character from russian, they become weird symbols. Is there any settings in jsreport or I need correct font in the server machine?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsreport.net/learn/phantom-pdf

> Phantom-pdf is currently not able to print some national characters by
>   default. To be able to print correct national characters into pdf you
>   need to set utf-8 charset in your html first.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  </head>
  <body>
     Česko
  </body>
</html>
```